# Beginner in Laravel Delete data using modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My modal works so well and can delete data but not the exact id that i selected to delete like example id: 1, 2, 3, 4 and i will select id: 4 but the id: 4 will not delete the id deleted is id: 1

this is my delete function inside AllSystemController

```
public function deletestorydata($id)
{
    $story = Story::findOrFail($id);
    $story->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data has successfully deleted.');
}
```

and this is my route web.php in story section

```
Route::get('stories/table', 'AllSystemController@indexstoriesdata')->name('stories.table');
Route::get('/stories/add', 'AllSystemController@createviewstories')->name('create.stories');
Route::post('/stories/storiesdata/submit', 'AllSystemController@submitstories')->name('submit.stories.data');
Route::get('/stories/view/{id}', 'AllSystemController@showviewstories')->name('view.story.data');
Route::get('/stories/edit/{id}', 'AllSystemController@editviewstories')->name('edit.stories');
Route::patch('/stories/{id}', 'AllSystemController@updatestorydata')->name('update.story.data');
Route::delete('/deletestory/{id}', 'AllSystemController@deletestorydata')->name('delete.story.data');
```

and this is my view  index_stories_data.blade.php

```
<table id="table-style-hover" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered nowrap">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="1%">Image</th> 
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Flagship</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($story as $row)
<tr>
    <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/stories_images')}}/{{$row->display_image}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="50"></td>
    <td>{{$row->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->is_flagship}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->category_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
    <td>
    <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/stories/view', $row->id)}}" target="_blank">View</a>
    <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/stories/edit', $row->id)}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" href="">Delete</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

this is my modal and script

```
<div class="modal fade modal-icon" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">

<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
</div>
<form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{url('/deletestory', $row->id)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<div class="modal-body">
  <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete it?</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-process" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm</button>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_form').on('delete', function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?"))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

and i tried to dd($story); value, example id: 1, 2, 3, 4, and i will select button to delete is id: 3 and the result in dd is id: 1 is there something wrong to my function? how can i fix this?

Comment: What is your `$row->id` in the context of the modal?

Comment: value inside story table, i retrieve the data inside the view @foreach($story as $row)--@endforeach thats why im using $row->id  in context of the modal

Comment: Would you share your blade's foreach loop in your question, so I can give you an answer

Comment: all blade you want to see?

Comment: @John only foreach loop,  `foreach` `endforeach`

Comment: look up i edited my view foreach loop

Comment: Yes, but the `@endforeach`?

Comment: look in modal and script section i wroted in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have js function to change the id of the item in your form action accordingly to the item that you want to delete? If not your id will always be 1 or whatever id of the first object in your data.

```
<form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{url('/deletestory', $row->id)}}">
```

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_form').on('delete', function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?"))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script> 
this is my js script

Comment: from your comment on the main post, you said you use foreach and endforeach between modal that means you're gonna have as many modals as items in your @story object, if i understand this right my question would be did you call the correct modal? Maybe try click delete button and use inspect tool to see if it's the correct id you want to delete.

Comment: Did you check the id in the form action="{{url('/deletestory', $row->id)}}" of the modal that pop up when you clicked the delete button if it matches the id in your clicked delete button? because as in see in your code you call the modal with the id "delete" but if you use foreach between modal, you will have many modal that has the id of "delete" and it would always call to the first modal with id of "delete".

Comment: i did`nt, i solve it i wrote script to change the id if i will click the delete button, thanks for the idea ...

Answer (score 0):

I edit your full code, don't use your js in your foreach.

Try this :

```
<table id="table-style-hover" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered nowrap">

 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="1%">Image</th> 
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Flagship</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

  <tbody>

  @foreach($story as $row)
    <tr>
      <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/stories_images')}}/{{$row->display_image}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="50"></td>
      <td>{{$row->title}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->is_flagship}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->category_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
             <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

            <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/stories/view', $row->id)}}" target="_blank">View</a>

            <a style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/stories/edit', $row->id)}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <!-- Delete method -->
            <a href="#" style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" data-href="{{ url('/deletestory', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-circle btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Delete">Delete</a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach

  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete !!!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <p class="my-0 font-weight-bold">Are you sure you want to delete this data???</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Delete Modal JS -->
<script>
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
  });
</script>
```