# Pass a variable to route in javascript while working with laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to minimize code by reusing it.

I have the following function to delete data from my table.

```
var favorite = '';
      var base = $('#base').val();
      if(confirm("You are about to delete record(s). This cannot be undone. Are you sure?"))
        {
          $.each($("input[name='delete_items']:checked"), function(){
              favorite = $(this).val();
              var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
              var data = $(this).val();
              var url = '{{ route("ajax.news", ":data") }}'; //want to change news with base variable
              url = url.replace(':data', data);
              $.ajax(
              {
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}", _method:"DELETE"},
                success: function (response)
                {
                    $('#'+favorite).remove();
                    toastr.success(response);
                }
              });
          });
        }
```

Is it possible? Or do I have to write this code on every file that contains `table`?

Comment: No, you don't. This is a bootstrap delete modal. I answered same question some days ago, with all code sample. you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500607/4575350

Comment: @STA Thanks. But I found a way to reuse the code. By changing url in routes/web.php

Answer (score 0):

Usually when it comes to delete record with an ajax request I add a (for example) data-href attribute to the element I want to delete, this attribute contains the url which i need to call to delete this item in the database.

If you found a solution by yourself you must, most likely , show it there instead of just telling us "I found the solution, thanks" just because in a near future someone can face your problem arriving here and found no solution ;)