# onclick pass value to popup modal laravel jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i have this $staff_data coming from controller in foreach loop and onclick add hour modal pop trigger.

```
<table class="table  table-striped table-hover" id="roster-managment-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Staff ID</th>
      <th>Staff Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($staff_data as $staff_data)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$staff_data['id']}}</td>
        <td>{{$staff_data['first_name'].' '.$staff_data['last_name']}}</td>
        @if($staff_data['start_time']==null)
          <td><a href="#" class="add-hour" data-staffId="{{$staff_data['id']}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roasterManagementShifts">Add Hour</a> </td>
        @else
          <td>{{$staff_data['start_time'].' - '.$staff_data['end_time']}}</td>
        @endif
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="roasterManagementShifts" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="modal-title" id="">Add Shift</span>
        <a href="javascript:viod(0)" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span class="material-icons">close</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="add-shift">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="">From Date</label>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" name="from_date" class="form-control datepicker" id="from_date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-sm-6">
              <label for="">To Date</label>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" name="to_date" class="form-control datepicker" id="to_date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="">Start Time</label>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" name="from_time" id="from_time" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="HH:MM">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="">End Time</label>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" name="to_time" id="to_time" class="form-control timepicker" placeholder="HH:MM">
                <input type="hidden" name="staffId" id="userid" value="{{ Auth::id() }}" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="separator-strip col">Apply On</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-between pt-3 form-group">
              <div>
                Sun
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Mon
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Tue
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Wed
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Thu
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Fri
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                Sat
                <div class="form-check mr-3">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addShiftRadio[]" class="form-check-input" value="1">
                    <span class="checkbox-style"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group mt-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2"> Cancel</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="add_shift"> Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i'm trying to get data-staffId value in modal popup but on show.bs.modal event not working:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#roasterManagementShifts').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var staffId = button.data('staffId')
    var model =$(this);
    var aro = modal.find('#staffId').val('staffId');
    console.log(aro);
  });
});
```

Is there any better way to pass value to modal popup?

Comment: This works for me, hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500607/4575350

Comment: in your js. `var button = $(event.relatedTarget);` should be `var button = $(e.relatedTarget)`

Comment: it was also a mistake but show.bs.modal event not triggering