# Is not deleting from bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal, delete-row

as you can see these code, the deleting button inside of pagination works fine without bootstrap modal, and then convert to bootstrap model, the bootstrap model is working fine once click the delete button, but the problem is not deleting it or do nothing. I can't figure out what I missing, I could be id number or jquery, I need help badly.

Foreach

```
              <thead>
              <tr class="center">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Account ID</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Restocking Fee</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($resellers as $reseller)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> accountid }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> password }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> companyname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> restockingfee }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reseller-> active}}</td>
                <td class="center">

                    <form action="{{ url('/admin/resellers', $reseller->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <strong><a href="/admin/resellers/{{ $reseller->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-mini" >
                        <i class="fas fa-pen fa-fw"></i>View</a></strong>
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-mini"><i class="far fa-edit fa-fw"></i>Edit


<a href="#" style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" data-href="{{ url('/admin/resellers/{reseller}', $reseller->id) }}"
     class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-circle btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Delete">Delete</a>
                </form>

                </td>
              </tr>

                @endforeach
              </tbody>

              <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Account ID</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Restocking Fee</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div>
```

modal

```
<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete !!!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <p class="my-0 font-weight-bold">Are you sure you want to delete this data???</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
  });
</script>
```

controller

```
   public function destory(\App\Reseller $reseller){

        $reseller -> delete();

        return redirect ('/admin/resellers');
    }
```

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: im not getting errors at all, when I press delete button inside of bootstrap model is not deleting, is just didn't do anything another word mean no action after pressed it

Comment: See  the console, may be error there

Comment: there are no error showing in console, please take look at jquery codes these code with variable name are correct with the inside of delete code inside of bootstrap modal! i felt like I missed something. pleas help thanks.

Comment: I gave an another answer here, with proprr way, how to delete using bootstrap modal. hope this can help you
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500607/4575350

Comment: If you dont understand the above example, then paste your full code (foreach loop in your blade), so that I can edit

Comment: i do understand it but i just do not understand why is not deleting edited and put foreach code please take look at that ... many thanks.

Comment: Where is `@endforeach` here,  update again please, with delete function also

Comment: just edit update endforeach sorry please take look thanks

Comment: I added an answer, if you get any error, then post here, I will try to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your blade, do this outside the `form` (not in form) :

```
@foreach($resellers as $reseller)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $reseller->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $reseller->accountid }}</td>
    <td>{{ $reseller->password }}</td>
    <td>{{ $reseller->companyname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $reseller->restockingfee }}</td>
    <td>{{ $reseller->active}}</td>
    <td class="center">

      <a href="#" style="color:black; font-weight: bold;" data-href="{{ url('/admin/resellers/', $reseller->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-circle btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Delete">Delete</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is the modal data :

```
<!-- Delete Modal -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete !!!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <p class="my-0 font-weight-bold">Are you sure you want to delete this data???</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Delete Modal JS -->
<script>
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks bootstrap modal is worksing fine but is not deleting  at all even I put outside of form.

Comment: no but i have managed how solve this with some of your idea from your code. many thanks.