# Get data attributes in a modal from a button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

A newbie would like to ask for a little help.

I want to do something with the content of the modal when it is open, But how can I get id from the opened modal?

**My code:**

```
<a class="pdfId btn btn-success" data-id="{{ $value['id'] }}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">view</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">view</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">order number: {{ $value['id'] }}</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS/Jquery:**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-id')  ;
});
```

Please help me with this situation. Appreciate all of your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63457190/4575350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is more **simple** and **dynamic** approach which will help not to `repeat` or `write` code again and again

You can simply use `relatedTarget` function to see which button you clicked on the then from their just get the `data-id` of that clicked button.

Also, in your modal show function you can use `$(this)` and get the `orderID` element apply the order `id` to your modal dynamically and show the `order-id` in your `modal`

Using this **approach** will let you have as many `button` you want but you will reusing the same modal again without having to write more `code`.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var getID = button.data('id')
  var getAdd = button.data('adress')
  var getCity = button.data('city')
  var getPostCode = button.data('postcode')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('#orderID').text('Order ID = ' + getID)
  modal.find('#Address').text('Address = ' + getAdd + ' , ' + getCity + ' , ' + getPostCode)
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="pdfId btn btn-success" data-id="1" data-adress="123 example street" data-city="Earth" data-postcode="46000" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>
<a class="pdfId btn btn-success" data-id="2" data-adress="100 example street" data-city="Earth" data-postcode="46000" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View 2</a>
<a class="pdfId btn btn-success" data-id="3" data-adress="150 example street" data-city="Earth" data-postcode="46000" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View 3</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">View</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span id="orderID"></span>
        <br>
        <span id="Address"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: got it but how to show another details on modal content?

Comment: @angga what details would you like in the `modal-content` you only have `data-id` ?

Comment: first i would say thanks for helping, i have {{ $orders['shipping']['address_1'] }}
             {{ $orders['shipping']['city'] }}, {{ $orders['shipping']['postcode'] }}, etc

Comment: @angga All this data is in your button as well ? is this along `data-id` ?

Comment: yap, I wan to show detail costumer name, adrees etc On modal body

Comment: thankyou dude @AlwaysHelping got it, but how to got line for order this my  script

(at)foreach ($orders['line_items'] as $value)
             {{ $value['name'] }} x {{ $value['quantity'] }}
             (at)endforeach

Comment: @angga I am not sure how you are using forEach loop with those attributes. Can you please post another question showing that code. According to stackoverflow guideline we need to post another thread if the question is totally different to what was asked. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can use the `$().on('click', function() {` function

**Example:**

```js
$('[data-target="#modal-one"').on('click', function() {
  alert('data-id: ' + $('#modal-one').attr('data-id'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-one">Modal One</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal-one" data-id="100" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">data-id attribute: 100</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you repeating the code again. This can done using one function

Comment: Its was just for an example, i am guessing his data-id attribute is getting added dynamically so he will be using only one modal. ill remove the second modal to keep it clean ;-)