# Modal not showing when data passed to it

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

i have been working on laravel project and i need to delete data from database by showing warning modal message. deleting part deals with controller and working fine.But when passing user id to modal modal is not showing up.

```
                   <tbody>
                    @foreach($userdata as $data)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $data->user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->Column2}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->Column3}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data->Column4}}</td>
                        <td><a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{ $data->user_id }}"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    
                </tbody>
                <div  id="exampleModal{{$data->user_id}}" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Data</h5>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p style="align-items: center">Data will be delete.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('delete')
                              <a type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
                              </form>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Your `@foreach` loops through multiple users, your modal doesn't, it only uses the last user. Also, `<div>` after `<tbody>` sounds wrong. [Bootstrap Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) might help

Comment: Why you make your modal dynamic `id="exampleModal{{$data->user_id}}"`?

Comment: @sta 1 to recive id from button

Comment: Dont make your model dynamic, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63457190/4575350)

Comment: You have put the modal outside your foreach loop. So, the modal gets the ID of the last user only.